Need all rows for each contractnumber where DeviceId = 'ALL' or if such an Deviceid do not exist all rows to this contractnumber
My table looks like this



tenant
contractnumber
deviceid
Price
type




1
20
all
0.05
1


1
20
all
0.02
2


1
20
all
0.07
3


1
20
xy7
0.03
1


1
20
xy7
0.005
2


1
20
xy7
0.04
3


1
20
rq9
0.05
1


1
20
rq9
0.02
2


1
25
am6
0.04
1


1
25
am6
0.03
2


1
25
am6
0.06
3



What I need is something like this



tenant
contractnumber
deviceid
Price
type




1
20
all
0.05
1


1
20
all
0.02
2


1
20
all
0.07
3


1
25
am6
0.04
1


1
25
am6
0.03
2


1
25
am6
0.06
3



So for each contractnumber I need ether the rows where diviceid = 'all' or if this not exist I need all rows for this contractnumber.

So what are you asking. "I need" isn't a question. What is the difficulty you're having solving the problem yourself? What about your attempt(s) isn't working? What is your attempt?

Can you explain in more detail what logic is used to omit rows in your expected outcome

You want all records with Deviceid='all'.  You then want to include any records where the contractnumber does not include 'all'.
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Deviceid='all'
OR contractnumber not in  
(
 -- contractnumber with ALL
 SELECT contractnumber 
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE deviceid='All'
)

fiddle



tenant
contractnumber
deviceid
Price
type




1
20
all
0.05
1


1
20
all
0.02
2


1
20
all
0.07
3


1
25
am6
0.04
1


1
25
am6
0.03
2


1
25
am6
0.06
3




Nice Solution..

a where clause with an or not exists can solve this
select t.*
from   tenant t
where  (t.deviceid = 'all'
        or
        not exists (select 1 
                    from   tenant t2 
                    where  t2.contractnumber = t.contractnumber
                    and    t2.deviceid = 'all')
       ) 

See this dbfiddle



tenant
contractnumber
deviceid
Price
type




1
20
all
0.05
1


1
20
all
0.02
2


1
20
all
0.07
3


1
25
am6
0.04
1


1
25
am6
0.03
2


1
25
am6
0.06
3




Thanks for your answer, works perfectly.
Unfortunately I can't tick both answers, even though this is the answer I found first in my search, but was definitely too stupid to get it to work.
